# Built in way to convert this data to dict or json in python

Tags: python

So I have an input of

```
s = "['some.dot.seperated.words.here[id=123,rapidId=76,state=CLOSED,name=james_simpson,startDate=2021-10-30T11:16:00.000Z,endDate=2022-12-23T11:16:00.000Z,completeDate=2023-01-02T11:07:43.518Z,activatedDate=2022-10-30T11:20:03.627Z,sequence=33643,goal=do something\nfun\nwith flags, autoStartStop=false]']"
```

and i want to end up with a python dict like

```
example = {
"id":123,
"rapidId":76,
"state":"CLOSED",
"name":"james_simpson",
"startDate":"2021-10-30 11:16:00.000",
"endDate":"2022-12-23 11:16:00.000",
"completeDate":"2023-01-02 11:07:43.518",
"activatedDate":"2022-10-30 11:20:03.627",
"sequence":33643,
"goal":"do something\nfun\nwith flags",
"autoStartStop":False
}
```

**The question I have is**: Is there a pre built way to achieve this, similar to json.loads?

I understand I could do something like:

```
    print("s\n", s)
    s2 = s[s.find("[") + 1 : s.find("]")]
    print("s2\n", s2)
    s3 = dict(u.split("=") for u in s2.split(","))
    print(s3)
```

but why would someone store it like that and require such wrangling ... :/

Answer (score 1):

I use a regular expression. How it works:

- `re.findall` finds all matches `<chars except =[],>=<chars except =[],>`.
- The `findall` function puts those matches into this `[(key1, val1), ...]`
- Dict converts it to a dictionary.

```
import re

string = """'['some.dot.seperated.words.here[id=123,rapidId=76,state=CLOSED,name=james_simpson,startDate=2021-10-30T11:16:00.000Z,endDate=2022-12-23T11:16:00.000Z,completeDate=2023-01-02T11:07:43.518Z,activatedDate=2022-10-30T11:20:03.627Z,sequence=33643,goal=do something\nfun\nwith flags, autoStartStop=false]']'"""

data = dict(re.findall(r"([^=\[\],]*)=([^=\[\],]*)", string))

print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
{
    'id': '123',
    'rapidId': '76',
    'state': 'CLOSED',
    'name': 'james_simpson',
    'startDate': '2021-10-30T11:16:00.000Z',
    'endDate': '2022-12-23T11:16:00.000Z',
    'completeDate': '2023-01-02T11:07:43.518Z',
    'activatedDate': '2022-10-30T11:20:03.627Z',
    'sequence': '33643',
    'goal': 'do something\nfun\nwith flags',
    ' autoStartStop': 'false'
}
```